# Pasting exact values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, spreadsheet

I apologize if the question title isn't very informative. I've got a long list of numerical codes that I'm trying to paste into a column in Excel. The problem is that the vast majority of these codes begin with leading zeroes, so when they're pasted into the spreadsheet, Excel cuts off those zeroes and I end up with a bunch of incorrect codes of varying lengths. I tried doing Paste Special and inserting the codes as text (they're actually varchar data types in the database I'm copying them from anyway) but so far it hasn't been any use.

How do I paste the exact values in Excel and avoid losing my leading zeroes?

Comment: format the column into which the values are going as Text.  Then paste the values.

Comment: Ahh perfect! That was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottCraner You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paste the values as the are coming in as text:

1. Select the column into which the values are to be pasted.
2. Format that column as Text.
3. Paste the values.

This should keep the number strings as text maintaining the `0` on the front of the string.

Comment: Hey king, you drop this 